# Check number and name of columns and stop script if wrong

Tags: powershell, csv, logging, try-catch

I'd would like to check the name and number of column of my csv and if one of the column's name or the number of column is incorrect stop my script. This would be my first check before beginning to play my script

```
COL1;COL2;COL3;COL4
```

So I'd like to check il I have 4 columns and if name of COL1= COL1, name of COL2 = COL2 etc...

Here is my addlog fonction where i'd like to implement my checking
I tried using the -error action stop but I've surely made a mistake

```
#Fonction LOG
 
$date = get-date -Format dd-MM-yyyy
$script:fichierlogencours = "Log_$($date).log"
 
function AddLog([string] $TYPE, [string] $TEXT) 
    {
    $LINE = (Get-Date).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy %H:mm:ss") + "`t" + $TYPE + "`t" + $TEXT
    write-output $LINE | out-file -append -filepath  "$pathlog $fichierlogencours" -force
    if (($TYPE -eq "[Warn]") -or ($TYPE -eq "[INFO]")) {$COLOR="Yellow"}
    elseif ($TYPE -eq "[Err]") {$COLOR="Red"}
    else {$COLOR="Green"}
    Write-Host $LINE -ForegroundColor $COLOR
    } 
 
#Variables Fonction LOG
 

$PathLog = "C:\Temp\"
$FilePath = "C:\Temp\TestH.csv"
$rejets = "C:\Temp\ScriptGenXML_LignesEnErreur.txt"

$liste = Import-Csv -path 'c:\temp\testH.csv' -Delimiter ';'
$countColonne = ($liste | get-member -type NoteProperty).count


Try{
      
    AddLog [INFO] "Traitement du fichier $filepath"
    $TestLog = Get-Content -Path $filepath -ErrorAction Stop    
    AddLog [OK] "Traitement du fichier $filepath OK"
}
Catch{

    AddLog [Err] "Erreur dans le traitement du fichier $filepath"
    AddLog [Err] "ERREUR : $($error[0].Exception.Message)"
    
}
 
### I tried implementing my if/else in my try but couldn't find a way to stop the script as soon as the number of column not equal to 4

 if ($countColonne -eq 4) 
    {AddLog [OK] "nombre do colonne OK"}
    else 
    {AddLog [Err] "Erreur dans le traitement du fichier $filepath, nombre de colonne incorrect devrait être égal à 4"}
```

I did like this but my script keeps continuing, Any idea on how to do this

```
Try{
      
    AddLog [INFO] "Traitement du fichier $filepath"
    $TestLog = Get-Content -Path $filepath -ErrorAction Stop    
    AddLog [OK] "Traitement du fichier $filepath OK"
     if ($countColonne -eq 4) 
    {AddLog [OK] "nombre do colonne OK"}
    else 
    {AddLog [Err] "Erreur dans le traitement du fichier $filepath, nombre de colonne incorrect devrait être égal à 4"}

}
Catch{

    AddLog [Err] "Erreur dans le traitement du fichier $filepath"
    AddLog [Err] "ERREUR : $($error[0].Exception.Message)"
    
}
```

Also I need to check names any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need a `try{..} catch{..}` here at all.
Also, there should be no need to both use `Import-Csv` and `Get-Content` on the same file

One way to do this is like:

```
function Add-Log([string] $type, [string] $text) {
    $line = (Get-Date).ToString('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss') + "`t" + $type + "`t" + $text
    $line | Out-File -FilePath  $script:fichierLog -Force -Append
    $color = switch ($type) {
        '[Err]' { 'Red'; break }
        '[OK]'  { 'Green'; break }
        default { 'Yellow' }
    }
    Write-Host $line -ForegroundColor $color
} 

#Variables Fonction LOG

$PathLog          = "C:\Temp"
$filepath         = "C:\Temp\TestH.csv"
$fichierLog       = Join-Path -Path $PathLog -ChildPath ("Log_{0:dd-MM-yyyy}.log" -f (Get-Date))
$expectedColonnes = 'COL1', 'COL2', 'COL3', 'COL4'

# read the Csv file
$liste   = Import-Csv -Path $filepath -Delimiter ';'
# get the header names as string array
$colonnesArray = $liste[0].PSObject.properties.name

$continueScript = $true
if ($colonnesArray.Count -eq $expectedColonnes.Count) {
    Add-Log '[OK]' "Traitement du fichier $filepath OK: No. de colonnes:  $($colonnesArray.Count)"

    # join the headers into a string for output in the log file
    $colonnesString = "'{0}'" -f ($colonnesArray -join "';'")

    # test if the headers are as expected (same names, same order)
    if (@(Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $expectedColonnes -DifferenceObject $colonnesArray -SyncWindow 0).Length -eq 0) {
        Add-Log '[OK]' "Traitement du fichier $filepath OK: Colonnes: $colonnesString."
    }
    else {
        Add-Log '[Err]' "Erreur dans le traitement du fichier $filepath Colonnes: $colonnesString."
        $continueScript = $false
    }
}
else {
    Add-Log '[Err]' "Erreur dans le traitement du fichier $filepath, nombre de colonne incorrect devrait être égal à $($expectedColonnes)"
    $continueScript = $false
}

if (!$continueScript) { exit }
```

An alternative way of testing if the headers are the same and in the same order, so without using `Compare-Object` could be to create a string for both the found headers (already in the code above) and to do the same for the `$expectedColonnes` array. Then simply test if both strings are equal:

```
    # join the headers into a string for output in the log file
    $colonnesString = "'{0}'" -f ($colonnesArray -join "';'")
    $expectedString = "'{0}'" -f ($expectedColonnes -join "';'")

    # test if the headers are as expected (same names, same order)
    if ($colonnesString -eq $expectedString) {
        # rest of code
    }
```